# Route [Controller@method] not defined

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to create a form with a corresponding controller method which adds a new record to the DB. Laravel Version is 4.1

**app/views/projects.blade.php**

```
<tr>
   {{Form::open(array('action' => 'ProjectController@createProject', 'method' => 'post'))}}
        <td>{{Form::text('project_number')}}</td>
        <td>{{Form::text('title')}}</td>
        <td>{{Form::text('client')}}</td>
        <td>{{Form::text('comment')}}</td>
        <td>
            {{Form::file('xmlfile')}}<br />
            {{Form::submit('Hinzufügen',array('class' => 'blue'))}}
        </td>
   {{ Form::close() }}
</tr>
```

**app/controllers/ProjectController**

```
<?php

class ProjectController extends BaseController {

    public function listProjects(){
        $projects = Project::all();
        return View::make('projects',array('projects' => $projects));
    }

    public function createProject(){
        /* handling the form data later
            .
            .
            .
            */
        return "Hello"; 
    }   
}
?>
```

**Routes.php**

```
// Project Routes
Route::get('/projects', array('as' => 'listProjects', 'uses' => 'ProjectController@listProjects'));
Route::get('/projects/{id}', array('as' => 'actionProject', 'uses' => 'ProjectController@actionProject'));

// Canal Routes
Route::get('/canals', array('as' => 'listCanals', 'uses' => 'CanalController@listCanals'));
```

**Error Message**

> ErrorException Route [ProjectController@createProject] not defined.
>   (View: /var/www/virtual/hwoern/laravel/app/views/projects.blade.php)

Show the existing projects with the list method in the projects view works fine. What have I overlooked?

Comment: Hi, can you share your routes?

Comment: `// Project Routes

Route::get('/projects', array('as' => 'listProjects', 'uses' => 'ProjectController@listProjects'));

Route::get('/projects/{id}', array('as' => 'actionProject', 'uses' => 'ProjectController@actionProject'));

// Canal Routes

Route::get('/canals', array('as' => 'listCanals', 'uses' => 'CanalController@listCanals'));`

Comment: I have found the problem, check the answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have received the `Route [ProjectController@createProject] not defined` because you haven't created any post route for action `ProjectController@createProject` yet.

You have to define the following route:

**route.php**

```
Route::post('new-project', array('uses' => 'ProjectController@createProject'));
```

Comment: Thank you! Just to make it clear, I have to define route, even if I never access the action via url?

Comment: you have to define routes for any URL and if you are pointing a controller method from links or form. Otherwise, no needed.

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.3, and I can't find where `route.php` is. I've found `\vendor\symfony\routing\Route.php' instead, but I'm not sure if this is the right file. Please help.