# L5 Paypal Integration - Finding Controller method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to integrate Paypal into my Laravel 5 site using this package:
http://packalyst.com/packages/package/netshell/paypal

When I go to: `/paypal/checkout` though, I get this error:

> InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 561: Action
>   App\Http\Controllers\PayPalController@getDone not defined.

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/paypal/checkout', [
    'as' => 'get-paypal-checkout', 'uses' => 'PayPalController@getCheckout'
]);
```

And this is the PayPalController:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Paypal;
use Redirect;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PayPalController extends Controller {

    private $_apiContext;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->_apiContext = PayPal::ApiContext(
            config('services.paypal.client_id'),
            config('services.paypal.secret'));

        $this->_apiContext->setConfig(array(
            'mode' => 'sandbox',
            'service.EndPoint' => 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com',
            'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
            'log.LogEnabled' => true,
            'log.FileName' => storage_path('logs/paypal.log'),
            'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
        ));
    }

    public function getCheckout() {
        $payer = PayPal::Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $amount = PayPal:: Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('EUR');
        $amount->setTotal(42); // This is the simple way,
        // you can alternatively describe everything in the order separately;
        // Reference the PayPal PHP REST SDK for details.

        $transaction = PayPal::Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount);
        $transaction->setDescription('What are you selling?');

        $redirectUrls = PayPal:: RedirectUrls();
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(action('PayPalController@getDone'));
        $redirectUrls->setCancelUrl(action('PayPalController@getCancel'));

        $payment = PayPal::Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('sale');
        $payment->setPayer($payer);
        $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
        $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

        $response = $payment->create($this->_apiContext);
        $redirectUrl = $response->links[1]->href;

        return Redirect::to( $redirectUrl );
    }

    public function getDone(Request $request) {
        $id = $request->get('paymentId');
        $token = $request->get('token');
        $payer_id = $request->get('PayerID');

        $payment = PayPal::getById($id, $this->_apiContext);

        $paymentExecution = PayPal::PaymentExecution();

        $paymentExecution->setPayerId($payer_id);
        $executePayment = $payment->execute($paymentExecution, $this->_apiContext);

        // Clear the shopping cart, write to database, send notifications, etc.

        // Thank the user for the purchase
        return view('checkout.done');
    }

    public function getCancel() {
        // Curse and humiliate the user for cancelling this most sacred payment (yours)
        return view('checkout.cancel');
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are probably using the POST method instead of GET. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919648/route-controllermethod-not-defined

Comment: @Luceos It's getting called in the script though? `$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(action('PayPalController@getDone'));` wouldn't that mean it accessed the method straight, without going through routes.php?

Comment: Ah, i understand and found the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although laravel allows you to generate url's to actions. I researched what happened in the code.

In the UrlGenerator class:

```
/**
 * Get the URL to a controller action.
 *
 * @param  string  $action
 * @param  mixed   $parameters
 * @param  bool    $absolute
 * @return string
 *
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function action($action, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
{
    if ($this->rootNamespace && !(strpos($action, '\\') === 0)) {
        $action = $this->rootNamespace.'\\'.$action;
    } else {
        $action = trim($action, '\\');
    }

    if (!is_null($route = $this->routes->getByAction($action))) {
        return $this->toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute);
    }

    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Action {$action} not defined.");
}
```

It will search for a defined route with the specified action and in fact returns a link based on that route. So you would have to define the route to PayPayController@getDone for it to work.